# OpenXml setting Text Size

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, openxml

Using OpenXML to export to word file, I search for text and replace it with another text.
The working code is this:

```
Dim body = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
Dim paras = body.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph)()
Dim txtOfDoc = body.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()

For Each para In paras
    For Each run In para.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run)()
        For Each test In run.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()
            If (test.Text.Contains(stringToReplace)) Then
                test.Text = test.Text.Replace(stringToReplace, "newString")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Now I would like to set the string "newString" with different font size ...

Comment: You have to edit or add a new FontSize object to RunProperties object of the Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is this:

```
Dim body = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
Dim paras = body.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph)()
Dim txtOfDoc = body.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()

For Each para In paras
    For Each run In para.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run)()
        For Each test In run.Elements(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text)()
            If (test.Text.Contains(stringToReplace)) Then

                Dim tbl As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table()
                Dim tr As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableRow()
                Dim tc As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell()

                tc.Append(getFontDraft("DRAFT"))
                tc.Append(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.StyleTableCellProperties(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCellVerticalAlignment() With {.Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableVerticalAlignmentValues.Center}))
                tr.Append(tc)

                tbl.Append(tr)

                para.AppendChild(tbl)

                Exit For

            End If
        Next
    Next
Next


Private Function getFontDraft(ByVal textIn As String) As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph

    Dim body As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body()
    Dim paragraph As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph()
    Dim run_paragraph As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run()
    Dim text_paragraph As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text(TextIn)

    Dim RunProperties As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.RunProperties = run_paragraph.AppendChild(New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.RunProperties())
    Dim Bold As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Bold
    Bold.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(True)
    Dim fontSize As New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.FontSize
    fontSize.Val = "32"
    RunProperties.AppendChild(fontSize)
    RunProperties.AppendChild(Bold)

    run_paragraph.AppendChild(text_paragraph)
    paragraph.Append(run_paragraph)

    getFontDraft = paragraph

End Function
```